# Visual Studio has suddenly stopped working (Linked List Code)

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, linked-list

every one
I've got an issue when working with linked list function. Visual Studio has just suddenly stopped working. The following is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct _listnode
{
int item;
struct _listnode* next;
}Listnode;

void printlist(Listnode *head);
void main(){
Listnode *head, *temp;
int i = 0;
head = malloc(sizeof(Listnode));
temp = head;
for(;i<3;i++){
    temp->item = i;
    if (i != 2){
        temp->next = malloc(sizeof(Listnode));
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    else
        temp = NULL;
}
printlist(head);
    }
    void printlist(Listnode *head){
if (head == NULL)
    printf("Your list is empty");
while(head != NULL){
    printf(" %d ",head->item);
    head = head->next;
}
printf(" \n ");
    }

    Output: 
    0 1 2
```

And then it has displayed the following message 
[image]

Could anyone tell me exactly what was going on? Any help will be appreciated much. Thank you

Best Regards

Comment: Ha, ha. I scrolled down and reflexively clicked Cancel. And I'm on Debian. :/

Comment: Other than being horribly formatted and the wrong signature for main, I don't see a lot wrong with it.

Comment: you sure you're running in Debug mode? It should have exceptions caught.

Comment: Hi, Shivan. I am newbie in VS. I didn't catch you, what's debug mode? How it affects my code? Thanks

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Exceptions?  Read the tag....this is C.  <stdio.h> is another clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set the final link pointer to NULL when creating the list.  You set temp to null when, presumably you want to set temp->next to null instead.

It is a lot more "robust" to keep the list in a valid state after every transaction.  Right now, you depend on an if statement inside the loop to convert the last iteration into an "end the list" operation instead of an "add to the list".  If someone were to change the for loop limits without changing that if statement to match, you'd be back to a broken list again.  Try something like this:

```
Listnode *head = NULL; /* start with an empty list */
Listnode *tail = NULL;  

for (i=0; i<3; ++i)
{
    ListNode *temp = malloc(sizeof(Listnode));
    temp->item = i;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
        head = tail = temp;
    else
    {
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
}
```

There is still an if statement in the loop, but it is instructive.  The loop body is how you might write a function to push a new list entry onto the end of a singly-linked list.  Keeping both a head and tail pointer makes this efficient, avoiding a loop to find the end of the list.

The point is that no matter how the loop is modified, the loop will add one entry per iteration, and the list will be valid at the end of each iteration.

Comment: It's made sense. Thanks a lot, Mike :)